# laravel New project - getting Index of /name instead of welcome page

Tags: php, laravel

I just created a new laravel project on XAMPP using the "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel name 5.2.29".

I get a list of files (Index of/) instead of laravel welcome page.

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: have you started your server?  usually `php artisan serve`

Comment: `5.2`?? That is a long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is 2 options for you to see the wolcome page.

1. Copy all the files (not folders) from public folder to index folder.
2. open terminal on this specific folder and write `php artisan serve` , in this terminal will provide you the link for welcome page.

NB: make sure you'r using latest version of XAMPP

Answer (score 5):

XAMPP can't find your index.php file which is inside your public/ directory try to set /public directory as your root directory to do so create a .htaccess in your root folder and add these lines

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now your web directory points to public

Comment: how you can do this? this code tested and it is working for me, on server too.

Comment: @Salama96. Thank you this worked for me. I made a new .htaccess in the index folder and pasted the lines and it works.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new .htaccess file in the root directory of a new Laravel project and it worked fine with this solution (now 11/26/2020). I use Laragon, and recently installed the new version of PHP 8.0 to test it. Among several compatibility problems I had, one was this case, but now it works fine.

Comment: @RaimundoBaravaglio same here (Laragon) and it's the best. .htaccess in root folder solves it. I also force https and non-www, the latter being useful later on production server, and only then the use of public folder. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Normal, because the one only directory who should be accessible via url in laravel is `public/`, so the below url will show laravel's homepage

```
http://localhost:3000/Application/public
```

But with Xampp, you can use apache virtualhost's feature to point `your-local-domain.dev` to `C:\Xampp\htdocs\Application\public`

Or of course you can use this commande

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using laragon just like me and you just added the project. What worked for me was simply restarting the laragon server.

If the above doesnt work, just simply switch the root directory settings and switch it back. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Locate your *.conf* file inside your */etc/apach2/sites-enabled* directory (for example: auto.myapp.test.conf ), open it. Add "*/public*" at the end of: *DocumentRoot* and *Directory*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/myapp/public"
    ServerName foco.test
    ServerAlias *.foco.test
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/myapp/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, restart apache server.